# How to execute a go binary file with crontab?

Tags: ubuntu, cron, binary

I have created a binary file from a Go script, and now I need to run it with crontab.
The binary file runs without issues executing it manually from the command line.
I am using Ubuntu from WSL.
Crontab saves successfully, but it seems the script does not execute.

Cronjob looks like this:

```
*/1 01 * * * /home/tgr/test-bin/main/main -download > /dev/null 2>&1
```

- I was testing this at 1 AM, that is why the crontab hour field is in 01.

Running the script with "-download" flag, tries to download some files from a bucket, using a YAML config file, then makes some secondary tasks like decompression, copying and verifying the structure of the files. It produces a log file too.

I have already started cron service with

```
sudo service cron start
```

Could you please advise?

Comment: Your schedule is just a complicated way of saying `* 1 * * *`. But the issue is must likely that you haven't started the cron service in WSL. See proposed duplicate.

Comment: Hello @Kusalananda, thanks a lot for your answer. 
I have already started the cron service, as I have stated in my edited description. Do you have something else in mind that could be causing this behaviour?
Thanks for the observation of crontab sintax, btw.

Comment: To debug, don't discard the output but save it to a file.  Is the file created.  If so, your job runs.  Does the file contain error messages, well, then you have other issues.

Comment: If you temporarily remove `> /dev/null 2>&1` you may get more clues in an email to root on that box.  I'm assuming it's running as root.  If not, does it have permissions to run and read/write all the relevant files as that user?

Comment: I have tried removing the discard of STDOUT and STDERR, but I don't find some mail or log folder. I am running crontab as my user (tgr) and all the files to read and write are under tgr's home directory.

Answer (score 2):

Jobs run through `cron`, or `at`, or `batch`, aren't run in the same runtime environment that you have on your desktop. None of your `PATH` changes, or other environment  variable settings are automatically propagated to  your `cron` job. For example, there's no `$DISPLAY`, so GUI programs need special treatment (read `man xhost`).

One can set environment variables for all one's `cron` jobs in the `crontab` file
Read `man 5 crontab`.

Look at the results of  `echo "=== set ===";set;echo "=== env ===";env | sort;echo "=== alias ===";alias` in each of your environments.

Since the `command` part of the `crontab` line is, by default,  interpreted by `/bin/sh`, which has a simpler syntax than `/bin/bash`, I recommend having `command` be a call to a `bash` script  (executable, mounted, starts with `#!/bin/bash`) which sets up the environment,  then calls the desired program.