# Bash script working in root but not in crontab

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting, cron

I'm trying to execute a bash script on Linux startup, but it doesn't work. I have tried all of these commands in the crontab:

```
@reboot bash /home/user/mysqlamazon.sh
@reboot sh /home/user/mysqlamazon.sh
@reboot /home/user/mysqlamazon.sh
@reboot sleep 60 && /home/user/mysqlamazon.sh
```

I have another command on crontab which works perfectly:

```
@reboot pwsh file.ps1
```

And I have also tried this command:

```
@reboot pwsh file.ps1 && sh /home/user/mysqlamazon.sh
```

None of these work! Any help would be appreciated!

Here is the content on bash script:

```
while($true)
do
./transfermysql.sh > file.txt
bcp tablename in file.txt -S ***********.com,**** -U **** -P *********** -d ********* -c
:> file.txt
sleep 60
done
```

Comment: A post that I like to refer to for crontab "situations" is: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/56491/117549

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't tell us how this fails, but I am guessing you don't see it executed.

First of all, your script will never work since `while($true)` isn't valid shell syntax. I assume you want something like this:

```
true=1
while(($true)); do ... ; done
```

The more common idiom for that is:

```
while : ; do ... ; done
```

Or (`true` is a command):

```
while true; do ... ; done
```

This is most likely because you are using relative paths in your script:

```
./transfermysql.sh > file.txt
```

Replace that with the full path:

```
/path/to/transfermysql.sh > /path/to/file.txt
```

Next, I also suspect that `bcp` is not in cron's PATH, so use the full path to that as well:

```
/path/to/bcp tablename in file.txt -S ***********.com,**** -U **** -P *********** -d ********* -c
```

Finally, I don't know why you would want `:> file.txt` since your first command overwrites its contents anyway, but if you do need it for some reason, you need to use the full path there too: `> /path/to/file.txt`.

Comment: Also, the `while($true)`. It actually works, but it's bogus as it relies on the variable `true` having an empty value, or being o simple command that returns success. I.e., running this with `true=false` would not work.  Better with `while true; do ...; done`.

Comment: @Kusalananda yes, works if `$true` is the name of a command. Or if it is a non`-0` number and you use `while (($true))`.

Comment: @SoftProgrammer because the cron script is likely not running from your home directory. In any case, as I said in the answer, you don't tell us how it "does not work" so all I can do is guess.

Comment: @terdon thanks a lot. The problem was on specifying the path of bcp.

Comment: Always paste your script into `https://shellcheck.net`, a syntax checker, or install `shellcheck` locally. Make using `shellcheck` part of your development process.

Comment: Thanks @waltinator!

Answer (score 0):

Jobs run through `cron`, or `at`, or `batch`, aren't run in the same runtime environment that you have on your desktop. None of your `PATH` changes, or other environment  variable settings are automatically propagated to  your `cron` job. For example, there's no `$DISPLAY`, so GUI programs need special treatment (read `man xhost`).

One can set environment variables for all one's `cron` jobs in the `crontab` file
Read `man 5 crontab`.

Look at the results of  `echo "=== set ===";set;echo "=== env ===";env | sort;echo "=== alias ===";alias` in each of your environments.

Since the `command` part of the `crontab` line is, by default,  interpreted by `/bin/sh`, which has a simpler syntax than `/bin/bash`, I recommend having `command` be a call to a `bash` script  (executable, mounted, starts with `#!/bin/bash`) which sets up the environment,  then calls the desired program.

Comment: Did you mean to post this as an answer to this question? What environment? What variables? Please don't post [identical answers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/647721/22222). Either the questions are the same (so vote to close as duplicates) or _adapt_ the answer to each question.

Comment: While this answer is generically true, it doesn't answer the question in a useful (specific) way. This answer would be useful to *troubleshoot* the situation, but clarifying the situation is better done as comments to the Question. Then the question can be updated with the details, and once the actual problem has been found, a specific Answer can be written up.